# Simplest way to profile a PHP script

Tags: php, profiling

What's the easiest way to profile a PHP script?

I'd love tacking something on that shows me a dump of all function calls and how long they took but I'm also OK with putting something around specific functions.

I tried experimenting with the [microtime](http://php.net/microtime) function:

```
$then = microtime();
myFunc();
$now = microtime();

echo sprintf("Elapsed:  %f", $now-$then);
```

but that sometimes gives me negative results.  Plus it's a lot of trouble to sprinkle that all over my code.

Comment: hey Mark, check out this comment to help you solve the negative comments: http://ro.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php#99524

Comment: That comment linked to by @Midiane doesn't make sense. If it seemed to solve the commenter's problem, it must have been a coincidence. Just using `microtime()` will lead to sometimes evaluating expressions like: `"0.00154800 1342892546" - "0.99905700 1342892545"`, which will evaluate like: `0.001548 - 0.999057`. You can use `microtime( TRUE )` to avoid that problem, as [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8807044/1034448) by @luka.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The [PECL APD](http://www.php.net/apd) extension is used as follows:

```
<?php
apd_set_pprof_trace();

//rest of the script
?>
```

After, parse the generated file using `pprofp`.

Example output:

```
Trace for /home/dan/testapd.php
Total Elapsed Time = 0.00
Total System Time  = 0.00
Total User Time    = 0.00


Real         User        System             secs/    cumm
%Time (excl/cumm)  (excl/cumm)  (excl/cumm) Calls    call    s/call  Memory Usage Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100.0 0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00     1  0.0000   0.0009            0 main
56.9 0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00     1  0.0005   0.0005            0 apd_set_pprof_trace
28.0 0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00    10  0.0000   0.0000            0 preg_replace
14.3 0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00 0.00    10  0.0000   0.0000            0 str_replace
```

**Warning: the latest release of APD is dated 2004, the extension [is no longer maintained](https://pecl.php.net/package/apd) and has various compability issues (see comments).**

Comment: The APD extension is broken on php 5.4.

Comment: In retort to user457015, I was able to get it to work on a website running wordpress 3.8.1 and PHP 5.3.10 and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: @Supernovah, user457015 did say PHP 5.4. He did not say it was broken on PHP 5.3.

Comment: @user1420752 I'm running 5.3.27 and it's not running there as well. I get an undefined function error.

Comment: Latest release of APD is from 2004(!) It does not work with PHP 7. When trying to install for PHP 5 with `pecl install apd`, it gives an error message about "config.m4". It seems like you have to install it from source, which I haven't tried yet. Seriously, isn't there a modern, updated CLI-based profiling tool for PHP that installs with Homebrew, requires minimal setup and gives easily human-readable output?

Answer (score 284):

You want [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) I think. Install it on the server, turn it on, pump the output through [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Home.html) (for linux) or [wincachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) (for windows) and it'll show you a few pretty charts that detail the exact timings, counts and memory usage (but you'll need another extension for that).

It rocks, seriously :D

Comment: I found this a lot easier to implement than the APD solution. But maybe that's because for some reason APD didn't compile properly on my system. Also kcachegrind's charts were as pretty as promised.

Comment: hi mercutio, which extension is it exactly that enables memory usage in the xdebug cachegrinds? I can't for the life of me get this to work.

Comment: @EvilPuppetMaster, you need to compile php with --enable-memory-limit or use a more modern php version. See http://www.xdebug.org/docs/basic#xdebug_memory_usage

Comment: xdebug + webgrind quickly became my weapon of choice for quick and easy profiling. http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/

Comment: xdebug + xdebug_start_trace() + xdebug_stop_trace() = win

Comment: This was very easy to get working on Windows with XAMPP. Already had netbeans configured for xdebug. The only thing you need to do is change an xdebug setting in php.ini to xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s" or else no output will be generated. Requires restart of apache.

Comment: This should be the best/accepted answer. Took me half an hour to get all things working (with compiling xdebug from source). Solid advise.

Comment: I think I'm using qcachegrind for windows. I tried webgrind but it never loads even small files. Just says "loading" forever.

Comment: Any way to get a text (non-GUI) report directly on the server?

Comment: If you are not using KDE then you might want to use qcachegrind instead, if you have qt installed already. For me it was 20mb vs 3mb installation.

Answer (score 115):

**No extensions are needed, just use these two functions for simple profiling.**

```
// Call this at each point of interest, passing a descriptive string
function prof_flag($str)
{
    global $prof_timing, $prof_names;
    $prof_timing[] = microtime(true);
    $prof_names[] = $str;
}

// Call this when you're done and want to see the results
function prof_print()
{
    global $prof_timing, $prof_names;
    $size = count($prof_timing);
    for($i=0;$i<$size - 1; $i++)
    {
        echo "<b>{$prof_names[$i]}</b><br>";
        echo sprintf("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;%f<br>", $prof_timing[$i+1]-$prof_timing[$i]);
    }
    echo "<b>{$prof_names[$size-1]}</b><br>";
}
```

**Here is an example, calling prof_flag() with a description at each checkpoint, and prof_print() at the end:**

```
prof_flag("Start");

   include '../lib/database.php';
   include '../lib/helper_func.php';

prof_flag("Connect to DB");

   connect_to_db();

prof_flag("Perform query");

   // Get all the data

   $select_query = "SELECT * FROM data_table";
   $result = mysql_query($select_query);

prof_flag("Retrieve data");

   $rows = array();
   $found_data=false;
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
       $found_data=true;
       $rows[] = $r;
   }

prof_flag("Close DB");

   mysql_close();   //close database connection

prof_flag("Done");
prof_print();
```

**Output looks like this:**

**Start**
   0.004303
**Connect to DB**
   0.003518
**Perform query**
   0.000308
**Retrieve data**
   0.000009
**Close DB**
   0.000049
**Done**

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is a code smell; it should always be `printf()`.

Answer (score 53):

### Profiling with XDebug

An extension to PHP called Xdebug is available to assist in [profiling PHP applications](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), as well as runtime debugging.  When running the profiler, the output is written to a file in a binary format called "cachegrind".  Applications are available on each platform to analyze these files.  **No application code changes are necessary to perform this profiling.**

To enable profiling, install the extension and adjust php.ini settings. Some Linux distributions come with standard packages (e.g. Ubuntu's `php-xdebug` package). In our example we will run the profile optionally based on a request parameter.  This allows us to keep settings static and turn on the profiler only as needed.

```
# php.ini settings
# Set to 1 to turn it on for every request
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
# Let's use a GET/POST parameter to turn on the profiler
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
# The GET/POST value we will pass; empty for any value
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value = ""
# Output cachegrind files to /tmp so our system cleans them up later
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
```

Next use a web client to make a request to your application's URL you wish to profile, e.g.

```
http://example.com/article/1?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1
```

As the page processes it will write to a file with a name similar to

```
/tmp/cachegrind.out.12345
```

By default the number in the filename is the process id which wrote it.  This is configurable with the `xdebug.profiler_output_name` setting.

Note that it will write one file for each PHP request / process that is executed.  So, for example, if you wish to analyze a form post, one profile will be written for the GET request to display the HTML form.  The XDEBUG_PROFILE parameter will need to be passed into the subsequent POST request to analyze the second request which processes the form.  Therefore when profiling it is sometimes easier to run curl to POST a form directly.

**Analyzing the Output**

Once written the profile cache can be read by an application such as [KCachegrind](https://github.com/KDE/kcachegrind) or [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind). PHPStorm, a popular PHP IDE, can also [display this profiling data](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/profiling-with-xdebug.html).

[image: KCachegrind]

KCachegrind, for example, will display information including:

- Functions executed
- Call time, both itself and inclusive of subsequent function calls
- Number of times each function is called
- Call graphs
- Links to source code

**What to Look For**

Obviously performance tuning is very specific to each application's use cases.  In general it's good to look for:

- Repeated calls to the same function you wouldn't expect to see. For functions that process and query data these could be prime opportunities for your application to cache.
- Slow-running functions.  Where is the application spending most of its time? the best payoff in performance tuning is focusing on those parts of the application which consume the most time.

*Note*: Xdebug, and in particular its profiling features, are very resource intensive and slow down PHP execution.  It is recommended to not run these in a production server environment.

Comment: Adding to the list of tools for parsing the profile cache: PhpStorm also has a tool for previewing the profile cache

Comment: @peter I forgot PHPStorm has that feature. I've added it with a link to the documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: Any way to get a text (non-GUI) report directly on the server?

Comment: @Mark could you mark this as the answer, please. The current answer was out of date even when posted and hasn't worked for many years.This doeswork, and I know of no better method.

Answer (score 27):

If subtracting microtimes gives you negative results, try using the function with the argument `true` (`microtime(true)`). With `true`, the function returns a float instead of a string (as it does if it is called without arguments).

Answer (score 24):

Honestly, I am going to argue that using NewRelic for profiling is the best.

It's a PHP extension which doesn't seem to slow down runtime at all and they do the monitoring for you, allowing decent drill down.  In the expensive version they allow heavy drill down (but we can't afford their pricing model).

Still, even with the free/standard plan, it's obvious and simple where most of the low hanging fruit is.  I also like that it can give you an idea on DB interactions too.

[image: screenshot of one of the interfaces when profiling]

Comment: New Relic looks promising, sure. However, "Disclosure of Your Application Data" part of their [Privacy Policy](https://newrelic.com/privacy) repelled me instantly. 

Imho, sharing pieces of **proprietary** source code with third parties is a little too much.

Comment: Not leaping to their defense here, but it looks like "Application Data" is just performance info and system config info, not your application source code.

Comment: Fir my new relic is showing my "WebTransaction" as 99% of the time, and dont have the pro account for "ApplicationTraces"

Comment: try signing up at: http://newrelic.com/rackspace < should give you "standard" for free

Comment: backup your original php configuration before installing new relic on your server as it massively updates the php config.

Answer (score 20):

Poor man's profiling, no extensions required. Supports nested profiles and percent of total:

```
function p_open($flag) {
    global $p_times;
    if (null === $p_times)
        $p_times = [];
    if (! array_key_exists($flag, $p_times))
        $p_times[$flag] = [ 'total' => 0, 'open' => 0 ];
    $p_times[$flag]['open'] = microtime(true);
}

function p_close($flag)
{
    global $p_times;
    if (isset($p_times[$flag]['open'])) {
        $p_times[$flag]['total'] += (microtime(true) - $p_times[$flag]['open']);
        unset($p_times[$flag]['open']);
    }
}

function p_dump()
{
    global $p_times;
    $dump = [];
    $sum  = 0;
    foreach ($p_times as $flag => $info) {
        $dump[$flag]['elapsed'] = $info['total'];
        $sum += $info['total'];
    }
    foreach ($dump as $flag => $info) {
        $dump[$flag]['percent'] = $dump[$flag]['elapsed']/$sum;
    }
    return $dump;
}
```

Example:

```
<?php

p_open('foo');
sleep(1);
p_open('bar');
sleep(2);
p_open('baz');
sleep(3);
p_close('baz');
sleep(2);
p_close('bar');
sleep(1);
p_close('foo');

var_dump(p_dump());
```

Yields:

```
array:3 [
  "foo" => array:2 [
    "elapsed" => 9.000766992569
    "percent" => 0.4736904954747
  ]
  "bar" => array:2 [
    "elapsed" => 7.0004580020905
    "percent" => 0.36841864946596
  ]
  "baz" => array:2 [
    "elapsed" => 3.0001420974731
    "percent" => 0.15789085505934
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 20):

You all should definitely check this new php profiler.

https://github.com/NoiseByNorthwest/php-spx

It redefines the way of how php profilers collects and presents the result.
Instead of outputting just a total number of particular function calls and total time spent of executing it - PHP-SPX presents the whole timeline of request execution in a perfectly readable way. Below is the screen of GUI it provides.

[image]

Comment: This is interesting, as I heard about this tool for the first time. When I was trying to set it up on mac, running `make` command throws error saying `not targets specified and no makefile found`. so need to dig a bit more to resolve those issues.

Answer (score 14):

[PECL XHPROF](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) looks interensting too. It has [clickable HTML interface](http://www2.xpay.cz/xhprof/xhprof_html/?run=4d95b7eaea1b9&source=xhprof_foo) for viewing reports and pretty straightforward [documentation](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html). I have yet to test it though.

Comment: That looks like it isn't getting much love. Last update in 2009, no PEAR packages for 5.3, 5.4 and beyond...

Comment: Facebook created a fork with support through php 5.5 https://github.com/facebook/xhprof

Comment: Check this fork also which proposes some additional adjustments : https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof

Comment: http://xhprof.io/ provides GUI for data collected using XHProf, as well as ability to store data in the database for historical analysis purposes. I am the author of the latter implementation.

Comment: Looks like some details has been updated. First, pecl now mentions the homepage of the project is at [github](https://github.com/longxinH/xhprof) and it's actively updated. This extension will generate the profiling data but to visulaise it, another package is required. I'm testing this out and will update here with GUI tool needed for this.

Comment: I'm testing GUI tool from https://github.com/perftools/xhgui, as it provides docker image which is easier to get it up and running in no time. but there is another tool available, and is referenced by php.net: https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof

Answer (score 10):

I like to use phpDebug for profiling.
http://phpdebug.sourceforge.net/www/index.html

It outputs all time / memory usage for any SQL used as well as all the included files. Obviously, it works best on code that's abstracted.

For function and class profiling I'll just use `microtime()` + `get_memory_usage()` + `get_peak_memory_usage()`.

Answer (score 8):

I would defiantly give [BlackFire](https://blackfire.io) a try.

There is this virtualBox I've put together using [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/), to test different php frameworks which coms with BlackFire, please feel free to fork and/or distribute if required :)

https://github.com/webit4me/PHPFrameworks

Comment: blackfire is good, and they also have a hack version, which is free to use (with limited functionalities). However, if you're a dev working behind a proxy, then it might be difficult, as this requires enabling some headers to make it working and it might be difficult, if the devops/security team doesn't want to allow it.

Answer (score 6):

For benchmarking, like in your example, I use the [pear Benchmark](http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark) package. You set markers for measuring. The class also provides a few presentation helpers, or you can process the data as you see fit.

I actually have it wrapped in another class with a __destruct method. When a script exits, the output is logged via log4php to syslog, so I have a lot of performance data to work from.

Answer (score 2):

XDebug is not stable and it's not always available for particular php version. For example on some servers I still run php-5.1.6, -- it's what comes with RedHat RHEL5 (and btw still receives updates for all important issues), and recent XDebug does not even compile with this php. So I ended up with switching to [DBG debugger](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_debugger.htm)
Its [php benchmarking](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_profiler.htm) provides timing for functions, methods, modules and even lines.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're a fan of VS Code, there is a quick and simple (free) extension [PHP Profiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.profiler-php-vscode).

This gives you simple function call times and hotpaths
highlighting right in your code.

[image: PHP hot paths in VS Code]

**More details**: https://docs.devsense.com/vscode/profiling