# How can I use a PHP code profiler for with Symfony CLI scripts?

Tags: php, symfony1, php-5.3, profiling

My environments include OS X with Zend Server CE and Ubuntu Server, Apache 2.  Developing with Symfony 1.4 & Doctrine on PHP 5.3.

I'm searching for a profiler that can be used with command-line PHP scripts as well as Apache-invoked PHP.  At the moment my need for command-line is actually more urgent than the web scripts.

I have already done some brute-force timing via logging microtime() intervals to good effect but I'd like to be able to get total times for each function being called and without so much hand-coding.

While my main concern is time profiling, a memory profiler would also be very useful.  Similar to using microtime() I've occasionally had to make repeated calls to memory_get_usage() before and after instantiating large objects or collections to get an idea how big their footprint is.

Comment: A discussion of various PHP profiling tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the final solution that I'm quite happy with.

I tried installing XDebug 2.1.1 via the command:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

However, this was failing miserably with this kind of error:

> Cannot find autoconf. Please check
>   your autoconf installation and the
>   $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable.
>   Then, rerun this script. ERROR:
>   `phpize' failed

After a bunch of searching I came across someone else who had tried this on OS X.  Fortunately they mentioned that installing Apple Xcode would provide the autoconf, phpize and other needed tools.

I got Xcode 3 and installed that, then re-tried the `pecl install xdebug` and it worked beautifully. After learning how to enable xdebug in my CLI instance of PHP and figuring out where the output files went, I then moved on to Webgrind.  Within a couple minutes of looking at my first webgrind report, I was happily pinpointing the areas of my symfony task to optimize.  It has been fabulous.

Also in my searching I happened across [this promising page about how to use Xdebug for MEMORY profiling](http://derickrethans.nl/xdebug-and-tracing-memory-usage.html). I haven't yet attempted this but wanted to add it here in case it helps anyone else.

---

I received one helpful comment with a link to a relevant discussion and two partial answers which were both helpful.  I gave each of those responders an upvote and indicated so.

I wish S.O. didn't seem to place such emphasis on accepting a single answer, but since it does, I'm writing a more complete answer and accepting it but made sure to give all the helpful responders upvotes.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

[XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) can do profiling. Well... it can gather profiling data for you. You can then use other applications to analyze this data. Follow the link for more information.

Comment: I gave you +1 for also pointing me to Xdebug.

Answer (score 3):

[webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) works really well for me

Comment: +1 for suggesting webgrind.  I love it.