# How to know running time of a specific function?

Tags: php, zend-framework, function, runtime

I am using PHP and Zend. Some of my code is taking too much time to execute. What is the best method to know that how much time is consumed by a specific function/constructors.

**For example:**

I am calling a function like this:

```
$insuranceModel = new Model_Insurance_Object();
$insurances = $insuranceModel->getInsurancesList();
```

**getInsurancesList** function in **Model_Insurance_Object** class

```
public function getInsurancesList() {
  // function body
}
```

What should I implement and where should I place ??

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to profile a PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/index.php) has a [Profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). It seems, that is exactly, what you are looking for.

Comment: also [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) is quite useful

Answer (score 1):

@KingChurch Great answer! :D If you don't want to go the .dll installation route, you could also write a little `benchit()` that times the operational runtime of any piece of code.

```
function benchit()
{
    list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    return (double)$sec + (double)$msec;
}

$start = benchit();
// ... Some code here
$end = benchit();
```