# How to debug script using xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I want something like this:

[Simplest way to profile a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)

But I can't install APD because I use windows and can't find any Windows binary  for APD :(

Can I do that with XDebug? If yes, how?

Right now I use WAMP with PHP 5.3.9 (has Xdebug enabled)

Comment: http://xdebug.org/download.php ?!?

Comment: Most IDEs have integrated xdebug support, and oftentimes also the profiler option. Oftentimes you want to configure a profiler dump and use [webgrind or kcachegrind](http://affinitybridge.com/blog/code-optimization-xdebug-and-kcachegrind) to see a pretty printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SET those variable :

```
 xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
 xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /some/directory
```

Open your the generated file with something like kcachegrind on linux, you could try [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) on windows.

More information [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).