# PHP: Function execution time for debugging

Tags: php, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to profile a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)

Sometimes my website loads slowly and I would like to trace which function causes it. (or if it is related to me or the webserver)
How can I get execution times of each function that is being run?

Like;

```
<?php
function A() { }
function B() { }
function C() { }
A();
B();

Trace();
?>
```

Trace() would output: A ran in 0,1 miliseconds, B ran in 1,1 seconds, script completed.
Is there any debugging feature like this in PHP?

Ps. I'm not speaking about applying microtime for each function.

Comment: you can use a profiling tool like the one xdebug offers [xdebug profiler documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Comment: You can try https://github.com/facebook/xhprof/ as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

- **[XHProf](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof/)** if you need to profile in production environments. It has a footprint, but it's usually affordable. It does not produce trace if the script ends unexpectedly though.

[image: http://blog.tech4him.com/wp-content/uploads/xhprof1.png]
[image: http://www.wiktik.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/xhprof-callgraph_small.png]

- **[XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)** if you want to profile in development and testing environments. It's generally more reliable, but has a noticeable footprint; long running scripts will generate very large (100s MBs) files for instance, as opposed to XHProf.

[image: http://blog.haohtml.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/win_xdebug_WinCacheGrind_4.jpg]

Don't use:

- **[APD](http://pecl.php.net/package/apd)**, because even though it's recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script), it's very outdated and doesn't look like it's being developed anymore (last release in 2004 according to its PECL page)

PS: My personal recommendation: Play with them all if you have the time to do so, or just set up xdebug in your dev environment otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to select it as the answer soon, but my question was about the production environment. It's typical linux hosting server that I have no access. Their MySQL server may have problems which causes the slow load, but in my development environment, I'm using my own MySQL server, so in the end I wouldn't be able to find the source of problems.

There is no other basic alternatives to the ones you mentioned above?

Comment: Hm not really, this kind of debugging can only be performed installing extensions to PHP; if you have no root access to the server the only thing you can do is relying on microtime benchmarks :/

Comment: Okay mate, guess I'll order a VPS or similar - would need it for my node server anyway. :p Thanks alot once again.

Comment: A more up to date link for XHProf is: https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this on your production site, but if you can replicate the problem in a test setting, use profiling to determine where you are spending all your execution time.  You'll need to install XDebug or equivalent.  http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler