# Debugging potential network bottleneck on AJAX calls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, performance

I've written some JS scripts on my school's [VLE](http://www.frogteacher.com/).

It uses the [UWA Widget Format](http://dev.netvibes.com/) and to communicate with a locally-hosted PHP script, it uses a proxy and AJAX requests.

Recently we've moved the aforementioned locally-hosted server from a horrible XP-based WAMP server to a virtual Server 2008 distribution running IIS and FastCGI PHP.

Since then - or maybe it was before and I just didn't notice - my AJAX calls are starting to take in excess of 1 second to run.

[image: FireBug output]

- I've run the associated PHP script's queries on PHPMyAdmin and, for example, the associated `getCategories` SQL takes `0.00023s` to run so I don't think the problem lies there.
- I've `ping`ed the server and it consistently returns `<1ms` as it should for a local network server on a relatively small scale network. The VLE is on this same network.

My question is this: what steps can I take to determine where the "bottleneck" might be?

Comment: It's hard to _guess_, but since IIS caches everything before actual output, any chance you're not "exit"ing your `ajax.php` when its work is done? Also, you can insert debug info (e.g. run time) into your returned text to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, test how long your script is actually running:
[Simplest way to profile a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)

Secondly, you should check the disk activity on the server. If it is running too many FastCGI processes for the amount of available RAM, it will swap and it will be very slow. If the disk activity is very high, then you know you've found your culprit. Solve it by reducing the maximum number of fastcgi processes or by increasing the amount of server RAM.