# Performance issues mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, query-optimization, database-performance

We manage a website for a client for us, this website is dealing with serious performance issues. This website is build within a CMS and is dealing with a maximum of 20 visitors at the same time. As long as the visitors of the website are the only users of the site, everything goes good. The CMS builds cache and the use of mysql query's is kept to a minimum.

The performance starts to lack when the employees of our client start to work on the site themselves. The whole workflow goes trough the site, this includes updating records in the database and inserting new ones. When records get update, deleted or inserted cache gets deleted so actions by visitors of the website will leed to query's.

My first question is should mysql be able to handle these requests ?
Even though the design of the database is not good (see below).
When i watch the processlist in mysql, i see simple querys taking up to 15 seconds.
these querys only seem to take so long when there are update or insert querys going on at the same time.

below the big table that is holding all the records.
everything used by the frontend of the website is stored in this one table.
including binarys. The table holds a total of 8,676 records.
The frontend has a lot of querys that uses a WHERE on for example Variabele5 or Variabele6
The value of these Variabele fields depend on the contenttype.

The WHERE is for example:

```
WHERE Variabele5 > 500 AND Variabele6 =2 AND contenttype = 35
```

The environment where all the employees work in does not get cached.
In this environment there are a few lists with order and search options.
These querys are memcached as much as possible, but when a record gets updated, deleted or inserted the memcache is cleared. This in combination with the insert, update and delete actions is probably the bottleneck.

So my question is should mysql be able to handle this all or is the design of the database to bad to handle the requests.

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|     Field     |     Type      | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| nr            | mediumint(80) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hidden        | int(1)        | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Title         | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| Body          | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Description   | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | mediumint(80) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| addate        | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| moddate       | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contenttype   | mediumint(80) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| parent        | mediumint(80) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Status        | mediumint(80) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| CODE          | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| menu          | mediumint(80) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filetype      | mediumint(80) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| folder        | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sortIndex     | bigint(255)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| servercache   | int(1)        | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| futurecache   | int(1)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| publishFrom   | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| publishUntil  | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pinned        | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| keywords      | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| latestversion | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| permalink     | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Integer1      | int(12)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Integer2      | int(4)        | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Integer3      | int(4)        | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Integer4      | int(4)        | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| Variabele1    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| Variabele2    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| Variabele3    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| Variabele4    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| Date1         | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| Date2         | varchar(255)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| Text1         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Text2         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Text3         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary1       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary1Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary2       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary2Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary3       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary3Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| browseAccess  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary4       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary4Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary5       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary5Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary6       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary6Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Integer5      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Integer6      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele6    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary7       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary7Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary8       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary8Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary9       | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary9Type   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary10      | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary10Type  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary11      | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary11Type  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary12      | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary12Type  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary13      | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary13Type  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary14      | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary14Type  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary15      | longblob      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Binary15Type  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Text4         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Text5         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Text6         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Text7         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Text8         | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele5    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele7    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele8    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele9    | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele10   | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele11   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele12   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele13   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele14   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele15   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele16   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele17   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele18   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele19   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele20   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele21   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele22   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele23   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele24   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele25   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele26   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele27   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele28   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele29   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele30   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele31   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele32   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele33   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele34   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele35   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele36   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele37   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele38   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele39   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele40   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele41   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele42   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele43   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele44   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele45   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele46   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele47   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele48   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele49   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Variabele50   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

indexes:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------+
|  Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Cardinality | Null |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------+
| PRIMARY     |            1 | nr           |        8675 |      |
| Status      |            1 | Status       |           5 |      |
| Status      |            2 | publishFrom  |        8675 | YES  |
| Status      |            3 | publishUntil |        8675 | YES  |
| CODE        |            1 | CODE         |        4337 |      |
| CODE        |            2 | Title        |        4337 |      |
| contenttype |            1 | contenttype  |          30 |      |
| Title       |            1 | Title        |        2891 |      |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------+
```

SERVER Information:
4x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU L5630 @ 2.13GHz

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 free -mt                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached |
| Mem:          4096       3841        254          0         44       1223 |
| -/+ buffers/cache:       2573       1522                                  |
| Swap:         1023        422        601                                  |
| Total:        5119       4263        856                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If i need to provide any additional information please let me know.

EDIT:Some example querys

The querys vary but here are some examples:

Search query for an employee:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT profiel.nr as nr, CONCAT(profiel.title,' ',profiel.Variabele49) as naam,profiel.Variabele3 as tel, profiel.Variabele44 as huurprijs, profiel.Variabele5 as inkomen, profiel.Variabele39 as  personen, profiel.Variabele46 as perdatum, profiel.addate as inschrijving, profiel.text1 as opmerkingen, medewerker.Title as m_naam,profiel.Variabele48 as lang FROM  site_content as profiel    left join vw_activeContent as medewerker on medewerker.nr = profiel.Variabele9  WHERE  profiel.contenttype =26  AND (profiel.Status=3 OR  profiel.Text8='Nee')  AND (  profiel.nr  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  profiel.title LIKE '%Rem%' OR ' ' LIKE '%Rem%' OR  CONCAT(profiel.title,' ',profiel.Variabele49)  LIKE '%Rem%' OR profiel.Variabele49  LIKE '%Rem%' OR profiel.Variabele3  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  profiel.Variabele44  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  profiel.Variabele5  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  profiel.Variabele39  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  profiel.Variabele46  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  profiel.addate  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  profiel.text1  LIKE '%Rem%' OR  medewerker.Title  LIKE '%Rem%' OR profiel.Variabele48  LIKE '%Rem%' OR profiel.Variabele1 LIKE '%Rem%' OR profiel.Variabele3 LIKE '%Rem%' )  ORDER BY  profiel.sortIndex
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+--------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+---+---------+--------------------+---+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| id | select_type | table |              |  type  | possible_keys  |                    |     key     |   | key_len |        ref         |   |             |            rows             | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+--------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+---+---------+--------------------+---+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      |       | profiel      |        | ref            | Status,contenttype | contenttype | 3 | const   |                    |   | 1700        | Using where; Using filesort |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      |       | site_content | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Status |                    | PRIMARY     |   | 3       | profiel.Variabele9 | 1 | Using where |                             |       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+--------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+---+---------+--------------------+---+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+
```

Search query visitor

```
EXPLAIN SELECT nr, title AS adres, Description AS description, Binary3 AS bin, Variabele2 AS 
TYPE , Text3, Text2 AS verhuurd, Integer2 AS kamers, Integer3 AS personen, Variabele4 AS inclusief, Text1 AS oplevering, Integer5 AS huurpijs, Variabele6 AS wijk, moddate
FROM vw_activeContent
WHERE contenttype =22
AND Integer2 >=2
AND Integer3 >=1
AND Integer5 >380
AND Integer5 <770
ORDER BY Integer5 ASC
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table |              | type |   possible_keys    |             | key |       | key_len |             ref             | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      |       | site_content | ref  | Status,contenttype | contenttype |   3 | const |     696 | Using where; Using filesort |      |       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------+
```

query that is widely used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT Variabele2
FROM site_content
WHERE contenttype =22
AND STATUS =1
ORDER BY Variabele2 ASC
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table |              | type |   possible_keys    |             | key |       | key_len |                     ref                      | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      |       | site_content | ref  | Status,contenttype | contenttype |   3 | const |     696 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |      |       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------------+------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: How about posting your queries, posting EXPLAINs on them to show how MySQL is executing them?

Comment: Please also show us the SQL Statement.

Comment: Are the sample queries you posted slow when executed in a MySQL prompt (as opposed to from PHP?)

Comment: That depends on the other activities on the server, if there are more querys waiting in the processlist the query can take up to 10 -20 seconds. If there is nothing else its executed in <1 sec

Comment: If the query is fast under ideal circumstances, it's probably not the query itself that's the problem, it's more likely either a poor use of transactions (are you using InnoDB?), or a server configuration issue - have you allocated enough memory to MySQL?

Comment: Probably yes, but how do i find this "problem". the table is MyISAM
Not sure where to find the allocated memory to MySQL. Is this in my.cnf?

Comment: i actually Never looked at the table type, can this be the problem ?
MyISAM locks the whole table when inserting or updating right ?

Answer (score 1):

From the only query example you have given, Variabele5 and Variabele6 are not indexed and there are probably lots of records with contenttype = 35, so queries are probably not using indexes very efficiently. More queries examples might help us get a better picture.

However, the table size doesn't seem very large, that makes me think the actual rebuilding of the cache might be the actual cause. So you might want to look at the caching policies used in the application. I don't know how much testing you might be able to do, but I'd try testing your scenario with caching turned off.

Comment: Variabele5 and Variabele6 are indeed not indexed, this is because the values of this fields vary per contenttype. so for contenttype 35 we could use the index but other contenttypes are using the field to with diffrent data. 

After cache gets deleted, its not rebuilding it all at once.
after a page gets visited, its getting cached so this is not really a heavy process. Same thing for the memcache.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your database is a mess, as you said. However, given your hardware, and the relatively small size of the data, I would expect the queries to be pretty fast.

If the queries are slow, it's likely because of the wildcards on the "where" criteria - `profiel.title LIKE '%Rem%'` for instance. You could replace that with full text searching.

Another design issue is storing binaries in the database; depending on the size of the binaries, this can have a big impact on disk IO performance, and - usually - the encoding/decoding of the binaries (which often requires the database connection to be kept open) can be significantly slower than just reading text/numbers from the result set. Consider caching the binaries on the file system, and only go to the database for them if you *know* they've changed.

However, before you dig into the database, I think you need to find a way of nailing down the performance problem, so you know you're fixing the right problem. Consider using a [profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script) to find the bottleneck, and then work on the specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thats exactly what im trying to do "nailing down the problem" before i start to optimize things that are not necessary. I'll take a look at the profiler link u provided thanks.