# Wordpress Website too much wait Time with Pingdom Tool

Tags: php, wordpress, vps, page-load-time

I'm working on a wordpress website:

```
- it's hosted on a VMWARE Linux Virtual Server with 2 core and 4GB RAM.
- it's the only website (development server) so no others website access.
- has Apache Module mod_deflate on text, html, javascript, css, xml
- it runs a lot of javascript stuff and the total size of the page is about 1,6 MB
- average cpu load is very low (0% to 5%)
- the server has 1GB RAM Free
- my ISP verified SAN access statistics and latency times are very low (some ms)
```

This is a load time test on Pingdom Website Speed Test:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dMWeVi/http://www.watcheswholesale.eu/

it shows **3,9 seconds of wait time**.

Is there a "check list" to understand why the server lose these seconds before sending content to the browser?
Thanks

Comment: I have no clue how the pingdom.com servers act. maybe it's their problem? Do you have any actual performance issues? complaints from clients?

Comment: The first step in sorting out speed issues is to understand what is making your site slow. Try [profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script) your site.

Comment: @Nanne All that is saying is that Pingdom has sent the request and has waited nearly 4 seconds before it got anything back from the server. Ive just had a 4.2 seconds time till first byte response from server

Comment: @Nanne: is very difficult to profile a wordpress site with tens of plugins...the only way is trying to disable and run again the test.

Comment: to verify server network performance I installed a new wordpress site with standard theme on the same server:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/esRGi1/http://ingrosso-orologi.com/
only 300 ms of wait time.
So I can exclude Network/VPS problem: is a software optimization problem....

Answer (score 1):

I did a profiling an a wordpress installation once, being embarrassed by such a loading time.

It turned out that the time can be reduced by half with some opcode cache like APC, and another half been taken by parsing an enormous `.po` localization file. Did a quick patch to cache it in a php array and finally got loading time within a second (which is still too much but barely bearable).

Now I am thinking that removing useless languages from that gettext file would also help.

The profiling itself was as silly as adding `microtime(1)`-based labels all ove the code

Comment: May be. But it took me a half an hour (an some thinking of where to put my labels). This way I've got sensible timetable which contained the only values I need instead of wall of numbers from xdebug. May be my idea of using xdebug is wrong though. Would be nice to see a good example

Comment: Generally takes < 5 minutes to add xdebug and get a proper profile of your code showing not only what was taking all the time, but what was being called and how many times things were called

Comment: The site is already running a cache function that is bundled with the theme.

Comment: @Anigel Thank you for the pointers. But I'd like to see not the advertising of the theoretical benefits but short, clean and comprehensible timetable.

Comment: @mascor that's indeed a problem.

Comment: @YourCommonSense We will agree to disagree then I see a clear comprehensive timetable which I can then drill down in to get much more useful information if needed which can be implemented and disabled in a fraction of the time it takes to pepper your code with random Microtime labels

Comment: @Anigel okay, your apologies accepted. Thank you for your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental problem is the site is taking too long to generate the page - I'd start by looking at how many DB calls are being made and how long they are taking - the query logs can help you with this.

You also need to turn on keep-alive so that you are reusing TCP connections but that'll only make a little bit of difference.