# in php get the files linked from each other

Tags: php, linux, debugging

I have a website with index.php. I am using linux

There are several other php files where the index.php file connects to for some functions.

How to get a complete list of all the php files that are called, and whatever times they are called.

How can I see the complete flow chart how the code is running. (I mean which are functions are being called from which php file)

I want to do it through linux command line. I dont want to install any ide. Presently i have vim with vdebug plugin. BUt in that i have to step into the entire code which is very time taking.

Comment: Are you trying to find what files get included for a single specific request or what files can be included at any time regardless of what actual request is made on any particular occasion

Comment: I am trying to find what files get included for a specified request. Like I have a page `sample.com/?p=10`. So in the commandline i type php index.php $GET=10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script Look at the answer about xdebug. When using kcachegrind you can see what files are included and what functions are called from them, how many times and a load of other info like how long is spent processing each function