# In general, how do I optimize a multi-tiered application's performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, apache

I have a LAMP website up and going.  It runs fairly fast, but would like to improve the speed.  I recognize you do not have the specific PHP script, SQL queries, whether caching is enabled, server configuration, etc, and not asking questions at that level.  Instead, I am asking whether there is a general best-practice approach and the order of the the steps to identify bottlenecks so that website speed could be improved.

Comment: There aren't really any general answers to questions like this. It's just a matter of looking at all the diagnostics, and noticing values that seem excessive.

Comment: @Barmar  Any thoughts on where you would start first?

Comment: Step 1: profile the execution. How much of the response time is spent in the user's browser, traversing the network, parsing the request, getting the necessary data, processing, assembling the reply, traversing the net back, and displaying the results in the user's browser? Apply recursively to the critical steps -- that's where specific techniques are used. But first, profile.

Comment: @mpez0  Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script provide a good approach to profile the execution?  If not, any recommendations?

Comment: @user1032531 I would start by asking on the correct site, maybe serverfault.com.

Comment: good tool http://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: @Barmar  I expect it will be considered off topic at serverfault even more so than here.

Comment: @barmar This is on topic for stackoverflow, but is not a specific question. If it was phrased "In general, how do I optimize a multi-tiered application's performance?", would you feel better?

Comment: @user1032531: that's a fine start. Anything from a stopwatch on down is a good way to get going. The important thing is to understand how much effect your current efforts *can* have relative to the overall application performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a general way to optimise for speed but personally every time I write a new section of code, I always know how long that code takes to execute simply by measuring it.

If you are retrospectively looking at a lot of code that's already been written, just break it down into sections and measure the time taken by each section.

I permanently have these lines wrapped around the main body of my code;

```
<?php

$start_time = microtime(true);    // Note the start time.
$html = get_html();               // Main body of code.

// Calculate peak memory usage and time taken.
$mem = number_format(memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024, 1).'mb';
$tmr = number_format(microtime(true) - $start_time, 2).'s';

echo "{$html}\n<!-- Peak memory usage: {$mem}. Response time: {$tmr} -->";

?>
```

That will show how long `get_html()` is taking. If you compare that to the waiting time reported by the browser, you can tell how much of the overall response time is consumed by your code and how much is consumed by things other than your code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Nigel,  Doing so only measures PHP and associated MySQL, but not network/apache/multiple requests, etc.

Comment: Indeed, but if you know how much time your own code is taking and you know the total time taken then obviously the network/apache time is the difference between those two. I'm not aware of a way to directly measure the network/apache time sorry. btw I don't think your question is too broad as is being suggested by the moderators. Slightly 'meta' questions are good.

Comment: Thanks Nigel,  I would have thought someone would have written a book on the subject.