# Why is my site load time so slow?

Tags: wordpress, hosting

For the site contractorsequipmentdirectory.com I have a full load time of over 22 seconds according to gtmetrix. According to my waterfall chart it is the very first get that is the problem.

I was on another host and migrated to Hostgator, since the migration the site load time has tripled. Hostgator absolutely refuses to help me at all with this issue.

I have another wordpress site with the exact same plugins and themes with a 4 second load time.

Comment: Use Chrome's Network explorer and view the waterfall of resources. After my request was sent, it took 784s for you to send me the first byte of response, you should examine your code for hotspots. Additionally, there were some images referenced by the page that also took over 2s to response, totaling 18s for me to render.

Comment: @MattClark It is Wordpress and I haven't edited any of the code. Do you have any recommendations on how to check for hostspots? I have this exact same setup on another host and get under 4s. I am using Cloudflare to help with the images and varnish on the backend. My ttfb was 7.06 in Google Network explorer.

Comment: Could it be heavy database queries against an under-equipped database? Does the database log any long queries? How about trying to [profile your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29022400/1790644)? Inject these at various points to see where your time is being spent. There is not solution to the posted question, as it depends on your theme, plugins, and environment as a whole.

Comment: What happens when you switch to default theme? Are the results of gtmetrix similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimise your website using result and recommendations from Google Page speed insights

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=contractorsequipmentdirectory.com&tab=desktop

Download optimised images, minify css and js file from bottom of page as shown in screenshot. Replace original resource with optimised downloaded resource.

Try to check combine css and js files if possible which will decrease number of requests. Decreasing number of requests will help in improving page speed.

Also try to validate HTML of your website using below url:
https://validator.w3.org