# How can I detect which function uses the cpu most?

Tags: php

How can I detect which function uses the cpu most?
I get around 20 reqs/s usually, but the cpu usage is around %50 which is terrible. I have no doubts about the server's performance as it is mine.

I need to find out the most cpu consuming function in my script but I don't know how to do it. I use custom script, I've written it all.

Comment: Which operating system are you using, cause it wont be the same method for every OS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to profile a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can get very good results with [Tideways](https://github.com/tideways/php-xhprof-extension) and [XHGUI](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui).

## UPDATE

#### Install latest community edition of MongoDB

1. Create file `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongo-org-3.4.repo` with the following content

   `[mongodb-org-3.4]
   name=MongoDB Repository
   baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
   gpgcheck=1
   enabled=1
   gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc`
2. Install MongoDB – `sudo yum install mongodb-org`
3. Run MongoDB for the first time (it will start automatically on boot) – `service mongod start`

#### Install PEAR (to have PECL), then the PHP extension for MongoDB

4. Run `sudo yum install php-pear`
5. Run `pecl install mongodb`
6. Add the extension to `php.ini` and restart PHP-FPM `extension=mongodb.so`

#### Install the Tideways extension for PHP profiling

7. Create file `/etc/yum.repos.d/tideways.repo` with the following content

   `[tideways]
   name = Tideways
   baseurl = https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qafoo-profiler/rpm`
8. Import the RSA key - `rpm --import https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/qafoo-profiler/packages/EEB5E8F4.gpg`
9. Install the extension – `sudo yum install tideways-php`
10. Edit the config `/etc/php-5.6.d/40-tideways.ini` and disable `autoprepending`

    `tideways.auto_prepend_library=0
    tideways.auto_start=0
    tideways.sample_rate=100`
11. Restart PHP-FPM – `service php-fpm restart`

#### Install the XHgui

12. Download from https://github.com/perftools/xhgui/archive/master.zip
13. Extract into `/var/www` and rename the folder from `xhgui-master` to just `xhgui`
14. Update permissions – `chmod 777 /var/www/xhgui/cache`
15. Make a virtual host for nginX and point it to `/var/www/xhgui/webroot`
16. Create indexes in **MongoDB**

    `$ mongo`

    `> use xhprof`

    `> db.results.ensureIndex( { 'meta.SERVER.REQUEST_TIME' : -1 } )`

    `> db.results.ensureIndex( { 'profile.main().wt' : -1 } )`

    `> db.results.ensureIndex( { 'profile.main().mu' : -1 } )`

    `> db.results.ensureIndex( { 'profile.main().cpu' : -1 } )`

    `> db.results.ensureIndex( { 'meta.url' : 1 } )`

    `> db.results.ensureIndex( { 'meta.simple_url' : 1 } )`

    `> exit`
17. Navigate to `/var/www/xhgui` and run the installer – `php install.php`
18. Setup an `autoprepend` directive in `php.ini` and restart PHP-FPM

    `auto_prepend_file = /var/www/xhgui/external/header.php`
19. To limit the disk usage of **MongoDB** (e.g. to 5 days = 432000 seconds)

    `$ mongo`

    `> use xhprof`

    `> db.results.ensureIndex( { "meta.request_ts" : 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds : 432000 } )`

Comment: Perhaps this could be worked and incorporated into @Steven's link.