# JS Countdown does not move seconds

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, countdown, countdowntimer

I am trying to pass time in microseconds from my PHP server to this Hilios countdown code. Well, it's passing and calculating correctly, but the countdown is static, I need it to keep updating until it resets:
01 days 00:00:10 (09, 08, ..., 00:00:00)

Any idea what I can do to keep the countdown updated, I tried setTimeout and interval, but to no avail. Thanks !!!

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.4.0/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
  
<!-- Include MomentJS library -->


<?php 
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo '<b>ServerTime</b> = '.date('D M d Y H:i:s').' GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)'; 
?>
<br><br>


<script>
  function horaServer(){
  return '<?php echo round(microtime(true) * 1000);?>';
 }

(function(factory) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([ "jquery" ], factory);
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
 
})(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var PRECISION = 100;
    var instances = [], matchers = [];
    matchers.push(/^[0-9]*$/.source);
    matchers.push(/([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source);
    matchers.push(/[0-9]{4}([\/\-][0-9]{1,2}){2}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source);
    matchers = new RegExp(matchers.join("|"));
   
    
   function parseDateString(dateString) {
        if (dateString instanceof Date) {
            return dateString;
        }
        if (String(dateString).match(matchers)) {
            if (String(dateString).match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
                dateString = Number(dateString);
            }
            if (String(dateString).match(/\-/)) {
                dateString = String(dateString).replace(/\-/g, "/");
            }
            return new Date(dateString);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Couldn't cast `" + dateString + "` to a date object.");
        }
    }
 
    var DIRECTIVE_KEY_MAP = {
        Y: "years",
        m: "months",
        w: "weeks",
        d: "days",
        D: "totalDays",
        H: "hours",
        M: "minutes",
        S: "seconds"
    };
 
    function strftime(offsetObject) {
        return function(format) {
            var directives = format.match(/%(-|!)?[A-Z]{1}(:[^;]+;)?/gi);
            if (directives) {
                for (var i = 0, len = directives.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    var directive = directives[i].match(/%(-|!)?([a-zA-Z]{1})(:[^;]+;)?/), regexp = new RegExp(directive[0]), modifier = directive[1] || "", plural = directive[3] || "", value = null;
                    directive = directive[2];
                    if (DIRECTIVE_KEY_MAP.hasOwnProperty(directive)) {
                        value = DIRECTIVE_KEY_MAP[directive];
                        value = Number(offsetObject[value]);
                    }
                    if (value !== null) {
                        if (modifier === "!") {
                            value = pluralize(plural, value);
                        }
                        if (modifier === "") {
                            if (value < 10) {
                                value = "0" + value.toString();
                            }
                        }
                        format = format.replace(regexp, value.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            format = format.replace(/%%/, "%");
            return format;
        };
    }
    function pluralize(format, count) {
        var plural = "s", singular = "";
        if (format) {
            format = format.replace(/(:|;|\s)/gi, "").split(/\,/);
            if (format.length === 1) {
                plural = format[0];
            } else {
                singular = format[0];
                plural = format[1];
            }
        }
        if (Math.abs(count) === 1) {
            return singular;
        } else {
            return plural;
        }
    }

// importante
    var Countdown = function(el, finalDate, callback) {
  this.el = el;
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.interval = null;
        this.offset = {};
        this.instanceNumber = instances.length;
        instances.push(this);
        this.$el.data("countdown-instance", this.instanceNumber);
        if (callback) {
            this.$el.on("update.countdown", callback);
            this.$el.on("stoped.countdown", callback);
            this.$el.on("finish.countdown", callback);
        }
        this.setFinalDate(finalDate);
        this.start();
    };
 
    $.extend(Countdown.prototype, {
        start: function() {
            if (this.interval !== null) {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
            }
            var self = this;
            this.update();
            this.interval = setInterval(function() {
                self.update.call(self);
            }, PRECISION);
        },
        stop: function() {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.interval = null;
            this.dispatchEvent("stoped");
        },
        pause: function() {
            this.stop.call(this);
        },
        resume: function() {
            this.start.call(this);
        },
        remove: function() {
            this.stop();
            instances[this.instanceNumber] = null;
            delete this.$el.data().countdownInstance;
        },
        
        setFinalDate: function(value) { // pega o valor de data-countdown
         //alert(value); 
            this.finalDate = parseDateString(value);
        },
  
  
        
        update: function() {
   
            if (this.$el.closest("html").length === 0) {
                this.remove();
                return;
            }
            //this.totalSecsLeft = this.finalDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
            /* setar hora do servidor */ 
   /* 
     function horaServidor(){
     
     //var qq = new Date("<?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s').' GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)'; ?>").getTime();
     //alert(''+qq);
     
     //return new Date("<?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s').' GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)'; ?>").getTime();
     return new Date("<?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s').' GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)'; ?>");
     //setInterval(horaServidor(), 1000);
     
     }
    */
 
 
      
    this.totalSecsLeft = this.finalDate.getTime() - horaServer();
   //this.totalSecsLeft = this.finalDate.getTime() - horaServidor().getTime();
   //this.totalSecsLeft = this.finalDate.getTime() - new Date('Sat Oct 26 2019 18:37:04 GMT-0300 (Horário PadrÃ£o de Brasília)').getTime();
   
            // this.totalSecsLeft = this.finalDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime();  LINHA ORIGINAL
            this.totalSecsLeft = Math.ceil(this.totalSecsLeft / 1e3);
            this.totalSecsLeft = this.totalSecsLeft < 0 ? 0 : this.totalSecsLeft;
            this.offset = {
                seconds: this.totalSecsLeft % 60,
                minutes: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60) % 60,
                hours: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60) % 24,
                days: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24) % 7,
                totalDays: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24),
                weeks: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7),
                months: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30),
                years: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365)
            };
            if (this.totalSecsLeft === 0) {
                this.stop();
                this.dispatchEvent("finish");
            } else {
                this.dispatchEvent("update");
            }
   
        },
        dispatchEvent: function(eventName) {
            var event = $.Event(eventName + ".countdown");
            event.finalDate = this.finalDate;
            event.offset = $.extend({}, this.offset);
            event.strftime = strftime(this.offset);
            this.$el.trigger(event);
        }
    });
 
    $.fn.countdown = function() {
        var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        return this.each(function() {
            var instanceNumber = $(this).data("countdown-instance");
            if (instanceNumber !== undefined) {
                var instance = instances[instanceNumber], method = argumentsArray[0];
                if (Countdown.prototype.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
                    instance[method].apply(instance, argumentsArray.slice(1));
                } else if (String(method).match(/^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i) === null) {
                    instance.setFinalDate.call(instance, method);
                    instance.start();
                } else {
                    $.error("Method %s does not exist on jQuery.countdown".replace(/\%s/gi, method));
                }
            } else {
                new Countdown(this, argumentsArray[0], argumentsArray[1]);
            }
        });
    };
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<b>Countdown</b>
<div data-countdown="2019/10/26 20:30:31"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/10/27 14:35:18"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/10/26 12:30:35"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/10/29 10:57:04"></div>


<script>

$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
  $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
    $this.html(event.strftime('%D dias %H:%M:%S'));
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to profile a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)

Comment: I had seen this post but it made no sense to me yet. But thanks for your attention !!! :)

Comment: just look into updating timers 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer
I didn't read all of your code but I suspect there's much too much of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk whats wrong with your code but I can help you with another one that I used (u can adapt it):

```
 <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Montserrat:900');
        .timer {
            color: #F6F4F3;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }

        .days,
        .hours,
        .minutes,
        .seconds {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px;
            min-width: 20%;
            margin: 1px;
            height: 70px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .days {
            background-color: #EF2F3C;
        }

        .hours {
            background: #F6F4F3;
            color: #183059;
        }

        .minutes {
            background: #276FBF;
        }

        .seconds {
            background: #F0A202;
        }

        .numbers {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            color: #183059;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>   
<?php 
foreach ($events as $index => $event) { ?>
   <div id="timer<?php echo $index; ?>" class="card-deck timer-wrap" data-event-date="<?php echo $formatted; ?>"></div>

<?php } ?>

<script>
        initTimers('.timer-wrap');

        function initTimers(selector) {
            var timers = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            if (timers.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
                    countdown(timers[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        function countdown(timerElem) {
            const year = new Date().getFullYear();
            const dat = new Date(timerElem.dataset.eventDate);

            let timer = setInterval(function() {
                const today = new Date().getTime();
                const diff = dat - today;

                let days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                let hours = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                let minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                let seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                timerElem.innerHTML =
                    "<div class=\"card days\"> \<div class=\"numbers\">" + days + "</div>days</div> \<div class=\"card hours\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + hours + "</div>hours</div> \<div class=\"card minutes\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + minutes + "</div>minutes</div> \<div class=\"card seconds\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + seconds + "</div>seconds</div> \</div>";

            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hello Pepescu Ion, I believe your example will help me yes, just a question please. Within the array, what date format did you use?
'YYYY-MM-d HH: mm: ss'?   

Olá Pepescu Ion, acredito que seu exemplo irá me ajudar sim, só uma dúvida por gentileza.  Dentro do array, qual formato de data você utilizou ?
'YYYY-MM-d HH:mm:ss' ?

Comment: 'October 28, 2019 22:37:00'
oh cool, it worked here. Thank you very much <3