# How do you output the encryption and decryption time in php

Tags: php, mysql, web

I need to output the time taken for the encryption of aes and twofish algorithm on a plaintext in php

i cant find a method to do it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime

Comment: https://github.com/phpbench/phpbench

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to profile a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can do like this:

```
function encrypt($plaintext, $password) {
    $method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $key = hash('sha256', $password, true);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext . $iv, $key, true);

    return $iv . $hash . $ciphertext;
}

$time = -microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < mt_rand(1,100); $i++) {
    $ct = encrypt("here_string", "here_password");
}

$time += microtime(true);
echo "Time: ",sprintf('%f', $time),PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: just want to ask on how can you convert the time in ms(millisecond)?